# SQL query to update

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this table employee with columns

```
name | salary
-------------
A    | 5000
B    | 2000
c    | 1000
```

another table 
works with columns

```
name| work
---------
A   | w1
A   | w2
A   | w3
B   | w4
B   | w5
```

I want to increase salary of employee by 100 per work and update only if number of works are greater than 1.
Can anyone help me out with this. I need a sql update query for this( no stored proc or trigger or cursor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using merge statement:

```
MERGE
INTO    employee
USING   (
        select distinct "name", count(*) over (partition by "name") cnt from works
        )x
ON      (employee."name" = x."name")
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     salary = salary+(100*case when cnt=1 then 0 else cnt end);
```

Comment: this query will add 100 even if employee has 1 work done

Answer (score 1):

here is proper query

```
update employee as a set salary = salary + 100 * NVL((
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM works as b
    where b.name=a.name
    group by name
    having count(*)>1), 0)
```

Comment: Actually I need 100 per work.I mean A should get 300 increment and B should get 200 increment and so on...